# While deploying in IIS getting error : The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am getting this error after deploying the code on the server or local IIS, but in debug mode everything is working fine. The message is clear that it is not able to find `index.cshtml` file but everything is in its place.

Application error:

[image: app error]

Project files:

[image: project files]

Assembly information:

[image: assembly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether `~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml` is available in your deployed application and also is in the correct directory, not your development location as you said it works in debug mode.

Comment: Yeah,i have created Home/index.cshtml file manually in published folder.  it worked,